# First character of cstring removed during ifstream c++

Tags: c++, fstream, c-strings, getline

The first character of cstring keeps being removed upon the second execution of getline in ifstream:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>

using namespace std;

int main(){

    char input[102];
    ifstream keyTextFile("key.txt");
    while (keyTextFile.getline(input, 102, '\n')) {
        cout << input[0] << input[1] << endl;
        cout << input << endl;
    }
    cout << input[0] << input[1] << endl;
    keyTextFile.close();
    return 0;
}
```

Currently, key.txt is one line:

```
0x0ffa331cc8765ddd
```

The code outputs:

```
0x
0x0ffa331cc8765ddd
x
```

The debugger shows input[0] changing from '0' to '\0' on the second execution of getline. How can I avoid this while allowing getline to scan a potentially large document?

please keep the answer to c-string implementation.

Comment: If the file is only one line, `keyTextFile.getline(input, 102, '\n')` fails on the second call and, [quoting cppreference](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/named_req/UnformattedInputFunction), *If the sentry returned false or sentry's constructor threw an exception... if the function was called to write to an array of CharT, writes CharT() (the null character) to the first location of the array*. So utterly vital to answering the question is how many lines are in the file?

Comment: You would also get the same behaviour if there is a second line, but the line is empty.

Comment: Quite hard to answer this question without knowing what is in the file you are reading. What makes you sure that ;`'\0'` is incorrect? As pointed out already, it would be correct for a blank line

Comment: use `std::getline` with a `std::string` and the problem probably goes away

Comment: @john I've added the contents of key.txt

Comment: what do you expect the second invocation of `getline` to do? You've asked it to read an empty line and its returned an empty string

Comment: @steve So as explained in the first comment. What you are seeing is the expected behaviour in the case of a single line. I guess to suggest what you should do instead we need to know what you are expecting to happen and why it matters to you that a failed call to getline alters the contents of your string.

Comment: my understanding was getline appends the new lines to the cstring rather than overwriting it. Is there a way to do that?

Comment: you could do `keyTextFile.getline(input + strlen(input), 102 - strlen(input), '\n')`